# Declaring a cursor in DB2 with other activity results in failed deployment

Tags: db2, zos

After looking around all over the Internet, I have to come back to SO :).

Summary:

DB2 stored procedure doesn't deploy when 3 lines are uncommented, otherwise it works perfectly fine. Any guesses why? FYI, I am rather new to DB2.

Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE(
    IN  P_ID INT ,
    IN  P_SEQ_NO_2 SMALLINT,
    IN  P_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0))

    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    FENCED
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    COLLID TESTDB2
    WLM ENVIRONMENT TDB2ENV
    ASUTIME LIMIT 5000000
    RUN OPTIONS 'NOTEST(NONE,*,*,*)' 
P1: BEGIN

    DECLARE V_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0);
    DECLARE V_LVL INT;

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE
    (LVL INT NOT NULL, SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL);

    SET V_LVL = 0;

    INSERT INTO SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE(LVL, SEQ_NO)
    VALUES(V_LVL, P_SEQ_NO);

    --**************************************************--
    --  If I uncomment following 3 lines, deployment fails --

    --DECLARE CUR_FFB CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    --SELECT * FROM SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE;
    --OPEN CUR_FFB;

END P1
```

Error:

> Deploy TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE(INTEGER, SMALLINT, DECIMAL(3, 0))
>
> Running
>
> TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE - Deploy started.
>
> Calling the build utility SYSPROC.DSNTPSMP...
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 1 1DB2 SQL PRECOMPILER         VERSION 9 REL. 1.0                                                        PAGE 1
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 2 0OPTIONS SPECIFIED: STDSQL(NO) NEWFUN(YES)  HOST(SQL) ONEPASS MAR(1,80) CCSID(37)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 3  DSNHDECP LOADED FROM - (SYS2.DB2T.DSNEXIT(DSNHDECP))
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 4 0OPTIONS USED - SPECIFIED OR DEFAULTED
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 5       APOST
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 6       APOSTSQL
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 7       ATTACH(TSO)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 8       CCSID(37)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 9       NOPADNTSTR
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 10       CONNECT(2)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 11       DEC(15)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 12       FLAG(I)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 13       HOST(SQL)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 14       LINECOUNT(60)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 15       MARGINS(1,80)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 16       NEWFUN(YES)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 17       ONEPASS
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 18       OPTIONS
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 19       PERIOD
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 20     NOSOURCE
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 21       STDSQL(NO)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 22       SQL(DB2)
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 23     NOXREF
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 24 1DB2 SQL PRECOMPILER         MESSAGES                                                                  PAGE 2
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 25 0DSNH016I E     DSNHPARS LINE 26 COL 10  "GLOBAL" REQUIRED
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 26  DSNH104I E     DSNHPARS LINE 26 COL 10  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "CUR_FFB". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: GLOBAL
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 27 1DB2 SQL PRECOMPILER         STATISTICS                                                                PAGE 3
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 28 0SOURCE STATISTICS
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 29    SOURCE LINES READ: 32
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 30    NUMBER OF SYMBOLS: 14
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 31    SYMBOL TABLE BYTES EXCLUDING ATTRIBUTES: 1952
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 32 -THERE WERE 2 MESSAGES FOR THIS PROGRAM.
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 33  THERE WERE 0 MESSAGES SUPPRESSED BY THE FLAG OPTION.
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 34  272544 BYTES OF STORAGE WERE USED BY THE PRECOMPILER.
>
> CONVERT SQLPRINT 35  RETURN CODE IS 8
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 1 DSNH016I E     DSNHPARS LINE 26 COL 10  "GLOBAL" REQUIRED
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 2 DSNH104I E     DSNHPARS LINE 26 COL 10  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "CUR_FFB". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: GLOBAL
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 3 CREATE PROCEDURE TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE(IN P_ID INT,IN P_SEQ_NO_2 SMALLINT,IN P_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0))RESULT S
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 4 ETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC CALLED ON NULL INPUT FENCED MODIFIES SQL DATA COLLID TESTDB2 WLM ENVIRONMENT TDB2ENV ASUTIME
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 5 LIMIT 5000000 RUN OPTIONS'NOTEST(NONE,*,*,*)'P1 : BEGIN DECLARE V_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0); DECLARE V_LVL INT ; DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORAR
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 6 Y TABLE SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE(LVL INT NOT NULL,SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0)NOT NULL); SET V_LVL = 0 ; INSERT INTO SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE(LVL,S
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 7 EQ_NO)VALUES(V_LVL,P_SEQ_NO); DECLARE CUR_FFB
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 8
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 9 SOURCE STATISTICS
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 10   SOURCE LINES READ: 32
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 11   NUMBER OF SYMBOLS: 14
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 12   SYMBOL TABLE BYTES EXCLUDING ATTRIBUTES: 1952
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 13 THERE WERE 2 MESSAGES FOR THIS PROGRAM.
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 14 THERE WERE 0 MESSAGES SUPPRESSED BY THE FLAG OPTION.
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 15 272544 BYTES OF STORAGE WERE USED BY THE PRECOMPILER.
>
> CONVERT SQLTERM 16 RETURN CODE IS 8
>
> DSNTPSMP CONSOLE 1 *** DB2 V9R1 SQL Procedure Processor DSNTPSMP 1.21 (PM09148 2010-03-23)
>
> DSNTPSMP CONSOLE 2 Language conversion warnings and/or errors, rc=8
>
> DSNTPSMP CONSOLE 3 PSM precompile is not successful, cannot continue
>
> DSNTPSMP Summary 1 Request: ALTER_REBUILD routine TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE did not complete.
>
> Build utility function requested: ALTER_REBUILD
>
> SYSPROC.DSNTPSMP - Returned +8
>
> TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE - Deploy failed.
>
> TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE - Roll back completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally it worked for me with slight modification, adding a solution for anyone who might come across this confusion later.

Solution - *Declare the cursor before you declare the table.*

Only thing that still confuses me is how can I create a cursor on an object that doesn't even exist yet.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTDB2.PROC_NAME_GOES_HERE(
IN  P_ID INT ,
IN  P_SEQ_NO_2 SMALLINT,
IN  P_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0))

RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
FENCED
MODIFIES SQL DATA
COLLID TESTDB2
WLM ENVIRONMENT TDB2ENV
ASUTIME LIMIT 5000000
RUN OPTIONS 'NOTEST(NONE,*,*,*)' 
P1: BEGIN

    DECLARE V_SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0);
    DECLARE V_LVL INT;

    DECLARE CUR_FFB CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT * FROM SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE;

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE
    (LVL INT NOT NULL, SEQ_NO DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL);

    SET V_LVL = 0;

    INSERT INTO SESSION.SEQ_NO_TABLE(LVL, SEQ_NO)
    VALUES(V_LVL, P_SEQ_NO);

    OPEN CUR_FFB;

END P1
```